# getQuote not working some stores

Tags: php, magento-1.9, checkout, tax

I Need to restrict the tax amount. so i went `Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php`
Then Finds **`calcTaxAmount()`** Tax Applying Function.  **I need to restrict tax who all are enter the tax vatid in checkout onepage tax should be zero**
so

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
    {
        $billing = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxvat();

        if($billing != "" )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }

        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        }

        return $amount;
    }
```

I added the new condition. its working some stores of multistores. Only one store cannot working properly. it causes user cannot register , and addtocart not working for that particular store. i found **getQuote** the issue. i remove the new condtion like below working fine.

Old Function:-

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }

        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        }

        return $amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Fixed Below Flow:-

Instead of Using GetQuote In Calculation.php Using Session Variable

> **Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php**

Function Name:- **public function saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId)**

```
        $assign = $this->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxvat();
        if ($assign !="")
        {
            $this->_checkoutSession->setVatSession($assign);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_checkoutSession->unsVatSession();
        }
```

Add Above code in the onepage.php  before **`return array();`** which means last of the function.

**Now Below  Get Accessing the Session Variable**

> Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
    {
        $sessionaccess = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getVatSession();
        if($sessionaccess != "")
        {
            return 0;
        }
        $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }

        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        }

        return $amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope this helps.

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
    {
         $currenQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
  $store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($currenQuoteId); 
        $billing = $quote->getCustomerTaxvat();

        if($billing != "" )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }

        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        }

        return $amount;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @user247217. I was Fixed. and I added the my answer.